# Tomcat hangs when enabling tomcat-users.xml

Tags: tomcat6

Disclaimer: I'm not a server admin.

<s>I recently put up tomcat on my home server and I intend to link it to my apache2 service. My issue here is that I can't even get manager as it seems that whenever i enable the tomcat-users.xml, tomcat will hang.</s>

For my Debian server, the users file is expected in `/etc/tomcat6/tomcat-users.xml`.
Prior to creating the file, tomcat responded as expected with the test page. Once I created the file, it stopped, and resumed to work when I removed it.

Testing through telnet confirmed my suspicions as it hung on GET / requests, though connected during that time.

My tomcat-users.xml file is as so ($user , and $password substituted)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<tomcat-users>

<role rolename="manager"/>

<role rolename="admin"/>

<user username="$user" password="$password" roles="admin,manager"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

This is a default tomcat6 installation, <s>so why would this cause a hang? how can I resolve this?</s>

The syntax and hanging has been resolved thanks to jmort253, however `<domain>:<port>/manager/html` is still unavailable. Is there something equally silly I'm missing here? the documentation points that the default package should have this stock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dots, should those be quotes in rolename?

```
<role rolename="manager" />
```

Like above?

Comment: silly me, this was it. It still however doesn't allow me to reach the manager web app.

Comment: What's the error message?  What's the path to the manager app on your computer, and what's the URL you're using to access it?

Comment: Typical 404, "The requested resource (/manager/html) is not available."

Comment: manager appears to be not included as webapps is located in `/var/lib/tomcat/webapps` which is only contains directory `ROOT` which itself only containing the default `index.html`. If this is not in the default package... where can I obtain this?

Comment: @Ken - Sometimes manager app isn't included in the webapps for security reasons.  You may need to move the folder to your normal webapps folder.  Also, check your server.xml to make sure your Host entry is pointing to the manager app.

Comment: It appears the debian package contains neither. I have no such manager that came with tomcat, i've searched the entire root. All the documentation points that it should be there.

Comment: @Ken - You may need to download the Tarball from the Apache Tomcat website.  http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi.  Sometimes, it's in a folder called "server".  If you don't find it in the production tarball, try downloading the source.  Also, check your server.xml, context.xml, and tomcat/conf/Catalina folders to see if you can find a Context entry that might tell you where the manager app is hidden.

Comment: I was never able to get the manager app working. For now I'm simply depositing the wars manually. Since jmort253 came closest to a solution (as well as solving my initial question before it became multi-part) I'll give credit where it's due

Answer (score 0):

```
<role rolename=.manager./> not this try this `<role rolename=manager/>`
```